# How to fill the UDP length in the first UDP fragment when UDP package divided to IP fragment?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, ip, network-drive

For example, one 2000 bytes UDP package(contains UDP header) and network MTU is 1500. So this UDP package should be split to two IP fragments. Only the first IP package contains the UDP header.
What value should be filled into UDP length in the UDP header of first IP package? 1480 or 2000?
Is there any document to confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP Length is the length of the UDP header AND the UDP data, in bytes.  The fragmentation will/should NOT change this.

[UDP] "Length  is the length  in octets  of this user datagram  including  this header  and the data" --RFC768, an Internet Standard.  It is also in the Stevens link referenced: "Referring to Figure 10-2, the UDP Length field is the length of the UDP header and the UDP data in bytes."

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this. Just set the UDP length to however big your data is.

IP fragmenting can occur at any router hop, without your knowledge (assuming you are the sender). It's the IP layer's responsibility to fragment and re-assemble the packet before the UDP datagram is delivered to the application.  Unless you're plugged in to the NIC driver, you won't be able to reliably tell if the packet was fragmented on the way.

If there's an IP fragment lost on the way, you won't get any UDP datagram at all, it will simply be lost from the application's point of view, even though the IP layer may have gotten 9 out of 10 fragments.

Everything about this is brilliantly described in Richard Stevens et al's seminal work: [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The protocols](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/internals/net/Richard_Stevens-TCP-IP_Illustrated-EN.pdf)
, section 10.7 IP Fragementation.

Comment: The problem is that we are doing generate fragment and re-assemble work in driver level. So this is the answer we need to know. We need to know the correct way or the protocol confirmed way to how to set this length.

Comment: I checked your link and this also has some mistake or confusion. it says "The length of a UDP/IPv4 
datagram is then the total length of the IPv4 datagram minus the length of the 
IPv4 header. ". So seems in this it says this UDP length should be filled with 1480 (1500 - 20).  I think this content doesn't consider fragment, only consider in application level. So still no exact text to confirm this.

Comment: The fact you're asking your question in the context of driver-level would have been useful information to have been included in your original post. Perhaps this question is better suited to be asked in the Network Engineering section of SE. Most answers here will be from an application point of view. Are you sure that figure 10-9 (section 10.7.1, page 489) doesn't explain what you are looking for?

Comment: No, that doesn't explain it. That also only explain on application level.

Comment: When you say "on application level", what do you mean? The figure I'm referring to visually explains concepts such as IP fragments, offsets, MF-flag, UDP header, UDP and IP lengths. This *not* something you have control over on an application level as it is typically implemented by the driver/IP stack. Might I suggest giving Richard Stevens et al's other book, "TCP/IP Illustrated: The Implementation, Vol. 2" a read? It might have the information you are looking for. It's has a plenty of C code that shows how the protocols are usually implemented, but perhaps a bit dated.

Comment: @Daniel
Regarding "set the UDP length to however big your data is":  UDP "Length  is the length  in octets  of this user datagram  including  this header  and the data" --RFC768, an Internet Standard.  It is also in the link you reference: "Referring to Figure 10-2, the UDP Length field is the length of the UDP header and the UDP data in bytes."

Comment: @Andrew That's exactly my point. When I wrote that, the OP hadn't told me that a he or she was developing a driver. What I meant was, from an *application* point of view, if you set the payload length to (say) 32 bytes, the UDP length field in the header with be 40 because there is code in the kernel that will automatically will add the size of the UDP header to the length of the datagram. Obviously, from a *driver* point of view, these extra 8 bytes need to be added by it, otherwise the payload would be truncated with 8 bytes.

Comment: @Andrew And yes, you are correct that fragmentation should not change that, just as the figure in my reference clearly shows.

Comment: @Daniel  Got it.  I sort of glossed over the app discussion; my bad.  :-)

Comment: @Andrew, No worries. And welcome to StackOverflow!